# Data not showing on Radar graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In order to generate a report through Excel, I need to

1. Convert a 9-point result scale to a 5-point scale
   `=IF(B4=0;"0";IF(B4=1;"1";IF(B4<4;"2";IF(B4<6;"3";IF(B4<8;"4";IF(B4<10;"5"))))))`
2. Plot the 5-point scale result on a table in seperate sheet
   `=Input!D4`
3. Generate a Radar graph from said table

I am stuck with #3 since the graph generated will not show the data from #2.

I've spent hours trying to fix this and simply has no clue. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Eval column not showing on graph:
[image: Eval column not showing on graph]

Eval column's  reference sheet:
[image: Eval column's reference sheet]

Comment: Steps 1 & 2 doesn't seem to be relevant to your problem now, please edit your question, remove what's not relevant and add more information about your problem. Please note that question here needs to be self-contained, references to external files are discouraged, instead please include your sample data as formatted text (can do it here: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), and some screenshots may help too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I included 1 & 2 as it may have caused the problem I'm facing with 3. I am unable to add sample data but have edited with screenshots. Do let me know if this provides a clearer picture to assist me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue is that you store "eval" as text, try modifying your formula removing quotes(`"`):

`=IF(B4=0;0;IF(B4=1;1;IF(B4<4;2;IF(B4<6;3;IF(B4<8;4;IF(B4<10;5))))))`